# Context is Hindi when printing line numbers in Word 2007

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007, arabic

I'm trying to print a Word 2007 document with Line Numbering turned on, and in Word the document looks fine but when I print the document, the line numbers appear in Hindi script.

See screenshots here: http://www.lessanvaezi.com/context-is-hindi-when-printing-line-numbers-in-word-2007/

I tried deleting my Normal template and allowing Word to create a new one, and testing using that, with no change. I also tried using different printers.

The problem goes away if I choose *Arabic* instead of *Context* under **Word Options** -> **Advanced** -> Show Document Content / Numeral.

However, I would like to keep this setting as Context. The question is, *why is the default context of my document Hindi script*? Is there a way to change this context?

Comment: Also made sure that there was only one Input Language, English (United States), with the keyboard set to US. Doesn't seem to affect the default for Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem

Choose System instead of Context under Word Options -> Advanced ->  Show Document Content / Numeral

Comment: True, that does have the desired effect, but I'm still curious as to why it defaults to Hindi numerals when set to Context. There's nothing about the context that points to Hindi, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this has to do with the language set for your default style. You can try setting it to English or so and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Good thought - I tried changing the settings on the default style, but it doesn't seem to affect the default numeral for printing.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the numeral type to Arabic, this problem solves and line numbering would not appear inappropriate when you get a print.

Comment: Where is this setting?